# Improving Average F1 Score for Multiclass Classification

Tags: r, classification, multi-class, h2o

I'm trying to do a multiclass classification with h2o in R. I stacked a model with a RF, GBM and deeplearning. The accuracy is ok (~0.81), but the average F1 score is bad because class B has a very high error rate. I understand 1 reason is because class B has very little samples (same for training set). Theoretically, what would be a good way to improve the accuracy/lower the error rate for class B?

A Error Rate: 0.1027 =   467 / 4,547
B Error Rate: 0.6847 =     393 / 574
C Error Rate: 0.2347 =   721 / 3,072

Total Error Rate 0.1930 = 1,581 / 8,193

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try using SMOTE or some way to generate synthetic data for the class B to balance the classes. UBL is a R packages which is quite useful.